# Laravel Eloquent - How to get nested relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, eager-loading

I have models: Competency, Objective, Rating and Teacher

With the following relationships:
**Competency** *hasMany* **Objective**
**Objective** *hasMany* **Rating**, **Objective** *belongsTo* **Competency**
**Rating** *belongsTo* **Objective**, **Rating** *belongsTo* **Teacher**
**Teacher** *hasMany* **Rating**

Tables:
**competencies**: id, title, etc
**objectives**: id, title, competency_id, etc [competency_id as FK to competencies]
**ratings**: id, score, objective_id, teacher_id, etc [objective_id and teacher_id as FKs]
**teachers**: id, first_name, last_name, etc

**Problem**

I want to return all teachers with their ratings grouped by competency and objectives like:

```
teacher1  
-- competency1  
---- objective1 score  
---- objective2 score  
-- competency2  
---- objective1 score  
---- objective2 score  
teacher2  
-- competency1  
---- objective1 score  
---- objective2 score  
-- competency2  
---- objective1 score  
---- objective2 score
```

I can get all competency grouped by objective and rating as:
Competency::with('objectives.ratings')->get();

How do I get the Teacher as the first level: teachers - competencies - objectives - ratings?

Comment: Thanks so much Kevin -  this works. Just one thing: in printing the score the implode function also prints the id of objectives. Is there a way to just output the score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shortcut that I can think of is making a **many to many** relationship between teachers and objectives, using ratings as the pivot table. So the distance between teachers and competencies is a bit shorter.

```
class Teacher
{
    public function objectives()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Objective::class, 'ratings');
    }
}
```

Later on, you can get all the data by saying:

```
    $teachers = Teacher::with('objectives.competency', 'objectives.ratings')->get();
```

And from the view you can do something like:

```
@foreach($teachers as $teacher)
    <h1>{{$teacher->first_name}} {{$teacher->last_name}}</h1>
    @foreach($teacher->objectives->groupBy('competency_id') as $groupedObjectives)
        <h2>Competency: {{$groupedObjecttives->first()->competency->title}}</h2>
        @foreach($groupedObjectives as $objective)
            <p>{{$objective->title}}: {{$objective->ratings->implode('score', ', ')}}</p>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```